# Why do I get a question mark in my localhost link? https://localhost:3000/?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication

I am using React to build a web app. And when I click the login button and make a http request, my localhost link will add "?" in the end.
My server works fine on the postman app, but would actually give a 204 as a response to my login request. So my login wouldn't work at the moment.

Below is my code for "Login.js"

My apologies for any confusion I've made.
Thank you for your help in advance.

```
enter code here
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Login.css";
import axios from "axios";

class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      errorMessage: "",
      isLoggedin: false,
    };
    this.handleInputValue = this.handleInputValue.bind(this);
    // this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
  }

  handleInputValue = (key) => (e) => {
    this.setState({ [key]: e.target.value });
  }

  handleLogin = () => {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    // if (!this.state.email || !this.state.password) {
    //   this.setState({ errorMessage: "Please check your email and password again." });
    // } else {
    axios.post("https://server.slowtv24.com/login",
      { email: email, password: password },
      { withCredentials: true }
    )
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("login post res>>>", res);
        // this.setState({
        //   isLoggedin: true,
        // })
      })
    // }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login">
          <div className="login-half left">
            <form>
              <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address" onChange={this.handleInputValue("email")} />
              <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.handleInputValue("password")} />
              <button onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div className="bar bar-top"></div>
          <span className="login-or">OR</span>
          <div className="bar bar-bottom"></div>
          <div className="login-half right">
            <button>Login with GitHub</button>
            <button>Login with Gmail</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  };
}

export default Login;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `form` tag for login form, because you are handling the submit action in `onClick` event.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login">
          <div className="login-half left">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter email address" onChange={this.handleInputValue("email")} />
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" onChange={this.handleInputValue("password")} />
            <button onClick={this.handleLogin}>Login</button>
          </div>
          <div className="bar bar-top"></div>
          <span className="login-or">OR</span>
          <div className="bar bar-bottom"></div>
          <div className="login-half right">
            <button>Login with GitHub</button>
            <button>Login with Gmail</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  };
```

Regarding the question mark, you can add type="button" to your button.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30491742/why-does-a-react-onclick-event-append-a-question-mark-to-my-url) for more information.

Comment: Thank you! My login problem is now solved, but the question mark still won't go away...

Comment: @Chelsie, updated my answer for the question mark issue.

Comment: Why remove the form? Using `onclick` is bad as it stops keyboard users from using the login.